# Fill a column with UserForm

Tags: vba, excel

I want to fill a column with UserForm. The user has 4 Options how the column can be filled. My Problem right know is, that only the first option works (2).
Also the input-mask wont disappear after I click the OK-Button. The chosen option should be copied into column H and filled automatically. Where are my mistakes?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' OK Button
Dim emptyRow As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set emptyRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:H" & lastrow)

If OptionButton2.value = True Then
    emptyRow.value = "2"

    If OptionButton3.value = True Then
        emptyRow.value = "3"

        If OptionButton4.value = True Then
            emptyRow.value = "4"

            If OptionButton5.value = True Then
                emptyRow.value = "5"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: to find your last row, I'd reccommend something like `lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row`. Also, your IF statements should be like `If` this `Then` that `ElseIf` this `Then` that `Else` that `End If`

Comment: To hide the Form after pressing the button, you have to add `Me.Hide` at the end of your code

Comment: After I indent your code maybe it's more clearer why . if the first `If` is false, then you don't enter all other `If`s...

Comment: @Tyeler Thanks! I changed the code based on your suggestions and now it seems like it accepts all options as an answer! But it also override my `H1` with the option and dont autofill. Also the Input-mask does not disappear after I click the Ok-Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot.. The biggest difference here is how the `If statement` is written. Your original code had `If statements` nested in each other, which is fine, but will not work for what you're trying to achieve. The statement I have written is **1** `If statement`. Another way you can do this is by `Select Case` statements. I'm keeping the code as similar to your original for ease of learning.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' OK Button
Dim emptyRow As Range, ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row 'A more flexible way to find last row
Set emptyRow = ws.Range("H2:H" & lastrow)

If OptionButton2.value = True Then
     emptyRow.value = "2"
ElseIf OptionButton3.value = True Then
     emptyRow.value = "3"
ElseIf OptionButton4.value = True Then
     emptyRow.value = "4"
ElseIf OptionButton5.value = True Then
     emptyRow.value = "5"
Else: MsgBox "No option was chosen.", vbOKOnly, "No Option Chosen" 'Catches no button selected
End If

Me.Hide 'This hides the userform. Another method is Unload Me which drops the cache as well

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That really helps alot! Actually didn't know about the "ElseIf"-Option.. I copied your code into mine and I've still got the problem, that the code overwrites my H1 and dont autill automatically. Edit: I changed `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row` into `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xl**Down**).Row`. Now he don't overwrite my H1 but the lastrow he choses is in cell 104mil.

Comment: I copy-pasta'd the code and ran it.. it works perfectly. Are you sure there aren't any differences in your's and this one?

Comment: I'm very sure! But this still helps me alot to achieve my work. Thank you very much!

Comment: I wish I knew why it wasn't working the same for you as it is for me.. If you get stuck let me know and I'll help.